# How do I create a clickable textView and then assign a button response to it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I searched a lot, and did not find this issue addressed:

I have an xml file I read, with records that contain the following data:

```
<abbrev> has an abbreviation, potentially from "A", "AAA", "ABC", ... to "ZIT"
<full_name> expands the acronym
<state_name> gives a description of what it is.
```

I want to display the following:

For each first letter that occurrs, "A" to "Z", I create a textView that contains that letter. (This textView is to be made clickable later).

Under each "First letter heading", I create another textView, and for each record whose  starts with that letter, I insert a formatted version of the next two entries in the record,  and .

I do that for the whole file.

So much I have made to work.

The problem comes with the next step:

I then make the "First letter heading" textViews clickable and assign a button behavior to them.

I get a double problem:

The code to make a button out of the textView requires getting the id from the R.java file.

How do I assign an id to the "First letter heading" textViews?

This is a very general question about making a dynamically designed textView to a button.

My first attempt yielded a message that clearly shows how little I know about Java (I am tackling Java coming from Quick-C!):

I am being told that "Cannot refer to a non-final variable letterContentTextViewArray inside an inner class defined in a different method.

I reckon that you pros don't even need a code exerpt to tell me where I f... up.

Thank you for your patience.

P.S.
I case I have to insert code, can somebody tell me how to do it?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you question correctly. You have a textview and you need to make that clickable. Assign a button response to it meaning you when you click on text view you need to do something??

Comment: To insert a code block, copy your code into your question, highlight it and then click the icon with the curly braces or hit ctrl-K on the keyboard.

Comment: I try to clarify, Raghunandan:

Yes, I make the "First letter heading textView clickable, so that when I click on it, I make the following textView, containing all the text for the given letter, View.VISIBLE or View.GONE. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, Jim, I had found out the hard way, when the system told me that I had to format my entry!